# How can I edit Contact Form 7 form fields programmatically?

Tags: wordpress, rest, api, contact-form-7

I'm trying to make a custom endpoint that changes the To: field in one of my contact form 7 forms. I see the entry in the database under post & post_meta but I'm not sure how to edit this. Do I use get_post() and make the required changes and update it update_post, or does CF7 have it's own methods/classes/functions I can use to edit this from the functions.php file?

Comment: what are you trying to do?  Change the label of the field ?